# Adding Widget (like TextView/button/etc.) or TextField (like PlainText/Date/Time/etc.) above a FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host

Taking cue from the example given in the Android Developer Site I was able to successfully have a FragmentTabHost inside a Fragment (dev site [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html)). I was able to put required number of Tab's etc.
However, I want to have a Widget (like TextView/button/etc.) or TextField (like PlainText/Date/Time/etc.) above a FragmentTabHost which i am unable to achieve.
Looking at the sample code in the android developer site I started doubting if this is possible because the Fragments OnCreateView() function returns the FragmentTabHost and there is no inflate of other UI elements being done.
My question : Is it possible to have other UI elements on top of a FragmentTabHost considering the fact that FragmentTabHost is added inside a Fragment.
If Yes: how do we go about it ?
If No: Possible alternative solutions.

Comment: Please learn [how to format your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) first. It's confusing.

Comment: @YuvaRaj changed the formatting. sorry for the annoyance (if any). Thought its better to keep it simple.  Any help on my question ?